# How to write to a textbox that is in another Form?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, textbox

I have a .NET application which has 2 forms: inside Form1 there is all the application stuff, while inside LogForm there is only a readonly textbox. I want to print some text to this textbox inside LogForm from Form1, while Form1 is performing all the work.

I open my LogForm via the

```
LogForm logForm = new LogForm();
logForm.Show();
```

But then? How can I do that?

Comment: You can  make the Textbox public. (See its modifier in the proprty pane!)

Comment: That was so easy...TY!!

Comment: Yup that was easy. There are more convoluted ways, esp. creating a public access funvtion in the log form.. (Unlike most of the answers below, which seem to miss the pint..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have the reference to this TextBox.

Put your access modifier to public in your visual studio form designer and access your TextBox by `logForm1.YourTextBox.Text += "new line \r\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You can make your LogForm to accept Arguments on initialization:

```
string ValueFromForm1 = null;
public LogForm(string input)
{
      ValueFromForm1 = input;
}
```

The on `Form_Load` set the value of textbox:

```
TextBox1.Text = ValueFromForm1 ;
```

Comment: You can set value in constructor too, just make sure it will be after `InitializaComponent()` line

Comment: @Fabio I know that but experiences show that new users have difficulties implementing it

Answer (score 1):

Either you can set the text in the constructor of `LogForm`:

```
public LogForm(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

or you can set the modifier of the `TextBox` to `Internal` (or even `Public`) on the Designer and then access it from `Form1` like this:

```
logForm.textBox1.Text = "Your text";
```

But keep in mind that while your program is working, the text will not show up on your `LogForm`, unless you repaint it, or use a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) to have the work be done in a different thread.

Comment: You don't need to "repaint" a form. If you set value straight to `TextBox.Text` it will be shown straight away

Comment: @Fabio: Depends. If the program is still "doing work" (as the OP suggested), the text will not show until the form has been repainted (which can be achieved by a simple "Application.DoEvents()". Wether this is good practice or not is off topic here). Or you have to use a BackgroundWorker to let the program do the work in a different thread.

Comment: OP call `Show` method every time, so if he set text to textbox and call `Show` it will be "repainting". Commented only because mention of "repainting" seems like OP need to do repainting manually

Comment: @Fabio: It's not really clear how the OP intends to use the LogForm, but I'm editing my answer right now to make it more clear. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

Create a public variable in Form1 and call in LogForm

Form 1

```
public static string logformtext;
logformtext="Required text"; //Value which you want to pass to LogForm
```

LogForm

```
TextBox1.Text=Form1.logformtext;
```